# Is this technically an O(n) algorithm?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity

From my understanding of algorithms, the following is technically a linear solution.

```
int max ( int * arr, size_t n )
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 100000000000000000000000000000; ++k)
        std::cout << rand(); // doesn't do anything useful   

    int largest = *arr; 

    for (int * offend = arr + n; arr != offend; ++arr)
        if (*arr > largest)
            largest = *arr;    

    return largest;
}
```

In fact, I can add as much garbage as I want to it, and as long as the number of operations **grows** linearly with respect to `n`, it's considered a "better" algorithm according to modern-day interviewers. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes; that's a fixed cost.

Comment: "Better" than what? The version without the busy-loop is also O(n).

Comment: It's a better algorithm from a complexity standpoint, but one that has been very poorly implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure what image you have of "modern-day interviewers" but I suspect that if you go into an interviewer thinking that the interviewers are irrational or idiotic, then you're less likely to have a good interview. But, then, why would you want to work for a company with interviewers like that?

Comment: @rici This isn't a carbon-copy of an interview question I've had, but I've had several incidences where I supposedly had an answer that was "wrong" because it wasn't the clever `O(n)` solution from the Crack the Coding Interview Book, even though the solution from the book actually requires a lot of patchwork to get all the corner cases, and a lot of operations within the loop. I come up with an 'O(n*log(n))` solutions that is 2 lines of readable code and covers all possibly cases, and it's considered wrong, somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically just ranting about code screens.

Comment: Honestly, what kind of answers are you expecting to a question like this? You already know that it's technically O(n) with a large additive constant in the loop body, so what's the point of this question, besides obliquely ranting about some bad interview you had?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I think it's reasonable for him to be asking if he's missing anything? Which, yes, he was missing something, which is that O() isn't everything, it's just one measure.

Comment: @neminem: to me it looks like he knows very well that it's just *one* measure, and, in facts, he is more or less implicitly saying that, by most other measures - such as readability, maintainability, elegance, maybe actual runtime in many cases - his code is better. It's understandable to feel frustrated by an interviewer who won't listen to a reasonable alternative to the solution he has printed in his book (I for one would appreciate a candidate that would show where one efficiency measure falls short, or where tradeoffs can be made), but, again, rants do not belong to SO.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it absolutely would be considered O(n) still. The first line is a constant (extremely large, but still constant) cost, so it doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity at all.

That said, the algorithm would only be considered universally "better" than a more sane O(n log n) algorithm, etc., according to an interviewer that had no idea what they were talking about. Any real-world discussion of algorithmic complexity, especially in comparing multiple options, absolutely should include asymptotic complexity, but also the constants involved (both multiplicative - 2n vs. 1000000n - and additive - n vs. n + 100000000), as well as the context it will be run under (for instance: suppose you were running a googol items through your algorithm: now your algorithm *might* be the better option.)

If I were asked this at an interview, that is what I would say, and most likely, what an interviewer would want to hear.

Answer (score 5):

**No, it is not O(n).**

If your compiler doesn't have an extended integral type with over 96 bits, it will be rejected as ill-formed.  If it does compile (128 bit integral types are not unheard of), the situation is potentially even worse...

The behavior, and therefore the complexity, are both undefined, due to overflow of the signed integer variable `k`.  On many sane compilers, this code will never terminate, which makes it worse than an algorithm with O(n<sup>n</sup>!) complexity... in fact, it's also worse than the tower of powers seen in [The Magic Money Machine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/13050/10031).

If you see this code in an interview, it leads naturally into a discussion of the merits of correctness over performance.

Comment: Excellent point made about the overflow!

Comment: Cute. I see a question of asymptotic complexity and I just assume a language-agnostic perfect theoretical language, even if it does look like c++. But yes, there is totally an overflow issue, even if I don't think that's what he was actually going for (you could probably make his question more in line with what he meant to ask by, say, splitting the loop into a couple loops, or just waiting on a timer or something.)

Comment: @neminem: The question IS tagged [tag:c] and [tag:c++] (I checked, before posting)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I agree with you (I upvoted you for being technically correct, and for cleverness). I just have a feeling it isn't what the question-asker actually meant by the question - but I could be wrong, lacking proof to the contrary in the form of the person coming back and specifying.

Comment: Even assuming `int` has enough precision to store such a value, that code *still* won't compile...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Are you referring to the missing `#include`s?  Clearly this is a snippet, not an entire compilation unit.  Or perhaps the fact that C doesn't have `std::cout`?

Comment: @BenVoigt Analyse `for (; int * offend = arr + n; ++arr)`

Comment: Surely not what was intended, but it is a legal infinite loop. Except for the lack of side effects. It is not optimization stable, but then nothing in this function is.

Comment: Since when did the expression `int * offend = array + n` result in a boolean value? *edit*: Hmmmmmm...

Comment: While your analysis is strictly correct, I think that OP was reasoning at "common algorithmic level" and there is no overflow at that point.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Then he should have specified a different language (perhaps [tag:pseudocode])